# ASP.NET and Remoting: "Failed to connect to an IPC Port: Access is denied."

Tags: asp.net, remoting, ipc

I have a c# .NET 2.0 Windows Service that listens on an IPC port for remoting requests.  The service runs as the "Local Service" account.

I have an ASP.NET application that attempts to make calls on the remoted objects.  The ASP.NET application runs on XP as IUSR_*MachineName*.  Calls on the remoted objects are failing with the error:

```
Failed to connect to an IPC Port: Access is denied.
```

I did some research and most solutions indicate that I need to set the "authorizedGroup" property on the remoting channel to a group that I want to allow to access to the IPC port.  So I did the following:

1. Changed my code to allow "Everyone" access to the IPC port:

> ```
>    HashTable table; // properties
>    //...
>    table.Add("authorizedGroup", "Everyone");                          
>
>    table.Add("portName", name);
>    // etc
>    IpcChannel  channel = new IpcChannel(table, clientSink,
>    serverSink);
> ```

2 . Then I added IUSR_*MachineName* to the local "Users" group on my machine, which I was hoping would make it included in the "Everyone" alias.

But I tried to run it again and i am still getting "Failed to connect to an IPC Port: Access is denied."

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I too am struggling with this.  Where did you get the property "authorizedGroup"?  This does not show up on the Microsoft page for any channel, and there is only one property for the IpcChannel...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397839%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/ce968b5b-04fe-46d2-bb75-73e367a8b0c3/net-remoting-in-windows-service) post solved it

It seems that windows service has some additional control over accounts.

Practically, you need to set authorizedGroup = "Everyone" both on server and client side.